# Get the largest value of a group from a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I'm fairly new to programming, so i hope it explain this ok.

I need to select the third highest value of for a group within a dataframe with similar format to the following

[image]

Using the above as a reference, i would like to get the following result list [image]

At the moment, ive put together the following

`df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(3).min())`

Which is providing the following result, where it looks like im getting the third value in a list that is sorted in an ascending order.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the third largest unique number in each group? if so, note the parameters of [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html).

Comment: Ya, im looking to keep the "third largest unique number" in each group.  I've cycled through the "keep" parameters but i seem to be getting the same result. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for you help, i got it sorted with the following` import heapq

df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda grp: min(heapq.nlargest(3, np.unique(grp).tolist())))`

Comment: Yeah, I just tried. `nlargest(3, keep='all')` doesn't work, because other values are not duplicates of the value in the top 3. I made so many mistakes today, sorry for misleading.

Comment: You can also use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) to deduplicate. I have tried this `df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Value']).groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(3).min())`.